# How to have a table trigger get the current row PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to set a trigger to a table to update a column "Duration" that is the duration between the start and end date on the row.  However, whenever I insert/update the column, the trigger does not work because SCOPE_INDENTITY() keeps returning null.  How can I fix this?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CalcDuration]
ON [dbo].[Event]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS

DECLARE @STARTED datetime
DECLARE @FINISHED datetime
DECLARE @ID int

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT @STARTED  = [Date & Time Started] FROM  dbo.Event WHERE [Event ID] = @ID
SELECT @FINISHED = [Date & Time Finished] FROM dbo.Event WHERE [Event ID] = @ID

UPDATE dbo.Event 
SET Duration = DATEDIFF (  hour, @STARTED, @FINISHED )
WHERE [Event ID] = @ID
```

Comment: Why are you not just using the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables?  These tables will contain the whole record including the PK, for every row affected, even when multiple rows are written at once...  *(Note: an updated row is one that appears in both `inserted` and `deleted`.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCOPE_INDENTITY()` returns only the last inserted identity value within  the current scope, so in case it's used inside trigger it would only return value after insert operation is performed in trigger - which is not a case here and therefore returns NULL.

I suppose you are trying to get the ID of inserted/updated value in which case table `INSERTED` can be used.

Next, you are making a big mistake by assuming your trigger is only going to work on single row, which is often not the case, because UPDATE and INSERT can work on multiple rows. `INSERTED` table luckily contains all the rows that are inserted/updated.

So your trigger should look something like this:

```
UPDATE e
SET e.Duration = DATEDIFF (hour, e.[Date & Time Started], e.[Date & Time Finished])
FROM dbo.Event e
INNER JOIN INSERTED i on e.[Event ID] = i.[Event ID]
```

And at last, also to point that this is completely unnecessary use of triggers. Same can be done (and should be) using computed column. So if you just change your column to:

```
ALTER TABLE  dbo.Event
ALTER COLUMN [Duration] AS DATEDIFF(hour, [Date & Time Started], [Date & Time Finished])
```

you will always have correct Duration without need for trigger.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `after` trigger for that (note : no need for AFTER DELETE), you can do

```
CREATE TRIGGER ai_event
ON event AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
as
BEGIN
UPDATE event 
SET  Duration  = DATEDIFF(hour, i.[Date & Time Started],i.[Date & Time Finished])
from event e 
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON (i.id = e.id)

END;
```

However, having `Duration` as computed [persisted] column seems to be a better option in this case...

```
ALTER TABLE event ADD Duration2 AS DATEDIFF(hour, [Date & Time Started],
[Date & Time Finished]) PERSISTED;
```